# Programa do Labirinto, como resolver?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados

Galera, é o seguinte, comecei a aprender Java no semestre passado e agora estou com essa bomba de Estrutura de Dados na mão!  Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Não consigo montar uma lógica funcional, então não quero códigos, quero apenas um meio de solucionar meu problema.

Segue o problema:

Escrever um programa que cria uma matriz de tamanho MxN, com M e N lidos do teclado, e
preenche todas as posições dessa matriz com valores 0 ou 1, aleatoriamente (colocar mais zeros que uns). Depois, o programa deve solicitar duas posições dessa matriz (linha e coluna) e determinar se existe um caminho formado somente por 0 que ligue as duas posições (problema do labirinto).

Comment: você pode não saber nada de java, mas você deve saber da matéria, correto? minha dica é: desenvolva a logica primeiro, já está desenvolvida? se não: pq não? o q te impediu?

Comment: Com backtraking ou sem backtracking?

Comment: Sei a sintaxe, mas até agora não consegui formular uma lógica que resolvesse o problema. Minha lógica ainda não está boa o suficiente para solucionar este probelma.

Comment: O que seria backtraking?

Comment: Minha dica é a mesma do @Math. Escreva a lógica sem pensar em linguagem ou se é possível ou não. Apenas escreve em portuguÊs mesmo passo a passo o que deve ocorrer ara chegar no objetivo final. Depois refine sua escrita e, aí sim, vá para a linguagem. Agora, uma dúvida, seu professor passou um problema a ser resolvido em Java e os alunos não sabem Java?

Comment: Tivemos a base de Java, mas nada aprofundado, a maioria do pessoal não tem a lógica pronta para solucionar problemas maiores, e matriz sempre foi um problema para a turma.

Quanto montar a lógica em português eu tenho noção de que devo preencher ela, depois verificar índice por índice, mas ainda assim não consigo montar o programa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos pensar juntos assim você já sabe mais ou menos como chegar à alguma lógica.

O maior desafio dos programadores é achar um caminho lógico e o mais simples possível para resolver problemas do dia a dia.

Vamos supor que tenha sido passado 4 x 4 para o tamanho da matriz.

Vamos pensar também que para descobrir o caminho teremos que testar sempre 4 posições. (cima x baixo x esquerda x direita) para verificar se tem 0 para poder "caminhar".

Mas temos as pontas da matriz que não são 4 posições.

Logo, nossa matriz com 4 x 4 tem 16 espaços e 12 desses irão ser testadas 2 vezes por serem os das pontas.

Quais são os da ponta? [0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][1,0][2,0][3,0][3,1][3,2][3,3][1,3][2,3]

Vendo esses campos o que concluímos? Sempre uma ou outra posição é a primeira ou ultima do array, ou seja, 0 ou 3.

Então como podemos validar se dá pra checar a posição?

Acho que a sua logica vai ser algo como:(onde x é vertical e y horizontal)
[x+1,y] (baixo) [x-1,y] (cima), x,y+1 e [x,y-1] (esquerda)

Sempre verificando se o elemento em questão x ou y que vai ser somado ou subtraído se ele é maior que o maior tamanho no caso 3 ou menor que o menor tamanho 0. Se for um dos 2 quer dizer que aquele caminho não existe.

Agora o código fica por sua conta ...

Acho que é +- por ai. =]

Edit. 
Vou explicar bem por cima essa situação de muitos caminhos possiveis pq to sem tempo.

Vamos dizer que vais precisar de 2 arrays e 1 flag. pra resolver isso.

1 array é o caminho percorrido(vamos chamar de a)
2 array é as opções de caminho(vamos chamar de b)
e a flag diz se tem outra opção de caminho anterior.

Então chego no caminho [2,2] que tem 3 opçoes possiveis.

Vc marco no array "a" a chave [2,2] como ultimo caminho valido

E no array "b" que pode ser um array associativo multidimensional, você marcou como:
chave('2,2') valor = array (opção 1, opção 2 e opção 3)
E flag = true.

Dai vamos dizer que você foi pela opção 1 e e andou 3 casas...
logo no seu array 'a' você tem 2,2 e + 3 caminhos. e sua flag true.

Chegou num "deadend" vc verifica flag = true ? sim
Dai vc vai ver o ultimo registro do array "b" que vai ser sua referencia do ultimo caminho de múltipla escolha. Digamos que o ultimo registro seja o chave 2,2 e as 3 opções, vc escolheu a 1 e não deu certo.
Dai vc vê sua chave que diz a ultima posição valida 2,2 logo vc apaga do array 'a' todas depois do 2,2 e apaga a opção 1 do array 'b' também porque ela não deu certo.
Dai tenta a opção 2 e segue a mesma logica.

Tem mil maneiras de fazer isso. Essa foi a forma que pensei agora. Espero que de certo ou pelo menos te inspire a achar a logica correta.

At.

Comment: Perfeito, mas e se acontecer de eu poder ir a direita ou a esquerda e minha escolha estiver trancada? Como faço para voltar para o momento da decisão?

Comment: Você não "vai" se estiver trancada né. Vamos supor que você tenha um controle que diga qual é a sua posição atual. Então a partir da posição atual, você checa as posições validas disponiveis. Se alguma delas for valida ou seja =0 você muda sua posição atual para ela. Se não for valida testa a prroxima, se não encontrar nenhuma, cabo as opçoes.

Comment: Acho que você quer saber se chegar em uma situação onde tiver 2 posições posiveis, dai vc escolhe 1 e chega num ponto trancado nessa, digamos 3 passos a frente. Dai teria que voltar na ultima valida para tentar outro caminho. Vou editar minha resposta pra abranger essa situação.

Comment: Exatamente isso @Guerra ...

Comment: Ótimo @Guerra, obrigada pela ajuda, agora vou pensar em como colocar isso em códigos. Assim que eu obtiver reputação suficiente marcarei sua resposta como útil!

Comment: Beleza Isabela, fico feliz em ajudar. E gostei do desafio também de pensar nessa logica, e digo não é simples parabéns para sua faculdade tabém.